# "You can't do this!" vs. "You can't be doing this!" Any difference?

Tags: verbs, imperative-sentences

https://www.facebook.com/complex/videos/367883957181836/

If I were the security guard, could I just say, "You can't do this!"

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can say either. There is actually a difference between *cannot do* and *cannot be doing*, the latter is like a juxtaposition - it uses be + ing and this usually is used for an ongoing action, for example if someone was graffitiing on some walls, then the security guard shouts: “*You cannot be doing this!*” and the person graffitiing on the wall says “*Well I am and I **can***”.

...

What the security guard is saying is like an oxymoron, when he says “You cannot be doing this” “cannot” in this case is not a certain probability of not being able to; (related [can not vs must not](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/19684)?) rather it is more like “should not” than “cannot”. Because they are able to do it, it is just frowned upon and illegal. I do not know if this usage of “cannot” is idiomatic... **but** there is certainly nothing wrong with that sentence. “*You must not be doing this!*”is a bit too  formal and “*You should not be doing this!*”-hypercorrect (sorry!).